# can't access Vagrant using ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using Vagrant to work, and i need to share my box with my co workers who travel.
So, i packaged this box with Vagrant command `vagrant package` and got a file .box.

So, in another PC, i added the box to vagrant with `vagrant box add my-box.box serv-dev` and run `vagrant up`.

In process to mount vagrant a problem occur when it's time to access to the Vagrant machine: generally three connection timeout and after, it's Authentication Failure.

Therefore, i ran `ssh-keygen` and obtained a key. So, i added this one in .ssh/authorized_keys but it still doesn't work...

I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Check -h option of vagrant and ask for more logs. This post should be on server fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i changed the private key in ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key and it runs !

Comment: Accept your answer if it fits for you or delete your question.  I think you should delete your question.